# Cannot create APK file using Marmalade

Tags: android, visual-studio-2012, build, apk, marmalade

I'm using VS2012 and I'm trying to build my application for Android, but APK file is not created when I build the application.

I'm doing this process using the Marmalade Hub and the "Package, Install and Run" option. Build process works fine and I get no errores, but when I process on the "Package, Install and Run" button I get the following message:

```
Please Build before deploying. To build, click "Build" or click "Open in IDE" and build GCC ARM Debug.
```

The following picture shows this process:

[Picture](https://devnet.madewithmarmalade.com/storage/attachments/1059-captura%20de%20pantalla%202014-02-21%2012.28.42.png)

Please help, I cannot advance on my project because of this situation!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem on the HUB that wasn't allowing me to run the "Package, Install and Run" process. For that matter, the actual problem was in the Package part of the process.

For some reason, when you use VS2012 to develop and you haven't installed Windows Phone for VS2012, the default option for the HUB is to check for "Windows Phone 8 C++ Development" tool installation and if not present, block Package build for Android. I also note that I'm using Windows 7, so I cannot install Windows Phone for 2012 module.

The solution I found was to simply configure Marmalade Hub correctly:

1. Open Marmalade Hub.
2. Press on Dependency Checker.
3. Depency Checker should start with the IDE's and Compilers tab opened. If not, open IDE's and Compilers tab.
4. Look for Windows Phone 8 C++ Development on the tab.
5. Choose "Work Without IDE" on the options.
6. Try to build the project again.

Best!

Answer (score 0):

You're doing it wrong. The build process has to be in the `IDE`, not in the `HUB`. Open the project in IDE(VS2012 in your case) by either clicking `Open in IDE` button in `Hub` or double clicking the `Mkb` file. Build and run your code in `x86` first to create the necessary bin files for groups and then build it using `GCC release compiler`. After that you can either run it using GCC compiler to open the deploy tool(default action for VS2010 and VS2012 desktop version) or running deploy tool from external tools (VS2012 for windows phone) or by running the deploy tool target (in XCode) directly. You can instead use `package, install and run` button in the hub if you've already filled the neccessary info deploy tool asked you.

Honestly I don't have trust on Hub and like to do the development using old school method with IDE and deploy tool. It always works.

Comment: Hi proGamer, thanks for your answer, but there was no reason for me to not use the Marmalade Hub, I'm trying to follow Marmalade directions for the time being at least. I found a solution, anyways.

Comment: Not using Hub is my personal preference. Since I found Hub buggy. Anyways that's great that you've solved your problem.

Comment: Yeah, I agree with that... HUB is very buggy. Best!